# playing stream video using UIWebView issue

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, video-streaming

I'm currently developing an ipad application that will play video from wowza streamiong server.

Plainly saying, I load video into UIWebView as follows:

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://fishki.tv:1935/vod/mp4:20100731194117.mp4/playlist.m3u8"];

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:videoURL];
UIWebView * WView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];

WView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,300,200);
[self.view addSubview:WView];

[WView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

It plays video ok (you can try yourself), BUT when i try to load another video (or even the same one) by changing videoURL and calling loadRequest method again, it plays only sound without video.
I'm starting to think that it is a bug in ipad simulator because I was unable to fix it anyhow.

I would be glad to hear any suggestions because I also was unable to find similar problem on the web. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The web view behaves erratically on Simulator. Can you try the same on a regular device? I believe it might actually be working.